# VS2010 - Package/Publish Web - Options Disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-6, msdeploy

The boxes that say "Include all IIS Settings in IIS Manager (used only for IIS Web projects) is disabled for an WCF Service and also for a WebApp I created.

Are these not "web projects"?  Why is this box disabled, and how do I enable it? 
I'm trying to do a test of MSDepoy, and I want it to copy the name of the application pool from the dev system.  (I have IIS6/WinXP on my dev machine.)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the "Include all IIS Settings in IIS Manager (used only for IIS Web projects)" check box enabled by opening the Project Properties and going to the Web tab.

(My setting for the Servers was "Use Visual Studio Development Server". This probably applies to "Use Custom Web Server" as well.)

When I changed the Servers to "Use Local IIS Web server", the setting was enabled.

I also re-opened the Project Properties windows before going to the "Package/Publish Web" tab, but this step may be unnecessary.

I hope this helps save some time. This one took a while for me to figure out.